# Python Django How to save choice using model class "CHOICE"?

Tags: python, django, database, save, choicefield

In my models.py, I have class with `LEVEL_CHOICES` and `Level`.
First I builded my project with a textfield `Level` and it worked. Then I decided to change my `Level` in order to give users only certain choices. Therefore I edited my models.py and I have now:

```
class Eleve(models.Model):
    FIRST = 'FIRST'
    SECOND = 'SECOND'
    THIRD = 'THIRD'
    LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        ('FIRST', 'School'),
        ('SECOND', 'HighSchool'),
        ('THIRD', 'University'),
    )
   Level = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, default='FIRST')
```

I think that there is a problem in my views.py because I'am able to save class `Eleve` through Admin app. I'm also using a decorator in order to have REcaptchaV2.

```
def Form(request):
        form = ResgisterStud(request.POST)
        if request.recaptcha_is_valid and form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=False)
                form.save()
                return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
        else:
                return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

my forms.py

```
class ResgisterStud(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Eleve
```

My Form.html

```
    <form action="{% url "form" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    {{ form.Level|add_class:"form-control" }}
                                </div>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
                            <div class="form-group g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***"></div>
                             {% if messages %}
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            {{ message }}
                            {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  You might need to show your ResgiterStud form and html.  You may also want to change the name of the function from Form to something Django doesn't use.

Comment: I am not getting any error, the only issue is that Data is not saved in my database. My form  is correctly displayed in my Template I have 3 choices but when I click on submit it do not save my choice and refresh the page.

Comment: So what is the html you have in place for the form?  Are you actually calling your function?

Comment: Your current html is not showing (or trying to show) any form errors you have.  Take a look at the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages

Comment: I took a look. But I don't really understand how form errors can have an impact on the fact that my data is not saved if I correctly completed my form. I plan to fix errors messages after I fix this issue.

Comment: If there are form errors, the form will not save.  Prove to yourself there are no errors by showing all of them.  It means that isn't an issue and you can then look into the next potential cause

Comment: to show form errors in your template add {{form.errors}} and {{form.non_field_errors}}

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I showed them with your command. The error was that I set max_length=3 but length of SECOND is 6. I fixed that and now it is working !